# jquery.validate.js file in MVC4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Does jquery.validate.js file required to work DataAnnoations validations in MVC4?

I removed this file from project, validations are not working, does it take important role for DataAnnonations validations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to work with DataAnnotations and have client side validation include below scripts.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

They are available as nuget packages as well.

So the jquery.validate.js is needed, but the other files as well.

And make sure

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Is set to true in your webconfig.

Comment: yeah, it is set to true but I removed those files. Now I need to add them back. Thanks